# Struts 2 multiple row delete on button click

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I want to delete all those rows which get selected by the `<s:checkboxlist>`, but I am clueless how to do it.

Also, I don't have any idea of the `name` attribute of `<s:checkboxlist>`, is it important? do I need to have a getter setter for that name attribute?

```
<tr>
<td class="tabletextcont"><s:checkboxlist name="checkbox" list="functionThatGeneratesAList"/></td>
<s:iterator value="functionThatGeneratesAList">
<td class="tabletextcont"><s:property value="val1" /></td>
<td class="tabletextcont"><s:property value="val2" /></td>
<td class="tabletextcont"><s:property value="val3" /></td>
<td class="tabletextcont"><s:property value="val4"/></td>
<td class="tabletextcont center">
<s:url id="deleteAllSelectedByCheckbox" action="Delete" escapeAmp="false">
<s:param name="prop1" value="%{val1}" />
<s:param name="prop2" value="%{val2}" />
<s:param name="prop3" value="%{val3}" />
<s:param name="prop4" ><s:property value="%{val4}"/></s:param>
<s:param name="prop5" value="val4" />
</s:url>
<s:a href="%{deleteAllSelectedByCheckbox}" cssClass="deleteLinks" onclick="showConfirmationBox('%{deleteAllSelectedByCheckbox}');return false;"><img alt='<s:text name="command.delete"/>' border="none" src="<s:url value="/images/delete2.gif"/>"/></s:a>
</td>
</s:iterator>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute is important for binding form fields to the action attributes.

If everything configured correctly then a checkbox tag generates a series of checkboxes.

Then chechboks interceptor has a lot of work to put parameters to the action context.

You should have getters and setters.

Comment: Based on click of delete button, i need to pass all those values that are selected by checkbox, so i need to pass a list of this values, this means i need to have a List<ofValues> in action class?

Comment: To pass all those values the list should be submitted rather than clicking on the delete button.